# How to style Menu Items in Navigation Drawer in Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to add style the Menu Items inside Navigation Drawer but I am unable to do so. I have looked up for some answers but couldn't done it.

[image]

Can anyone help, I would be grateful.

I am using the following theme **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="Book Now!">
            <menu>
                <item android:title="item 1"
                    android:id="@+id/item1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
                <item android:title="item 2"
                    android:id="@+id/item2"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
                <item android:title="item 3"
                    android:id="@+id/item3"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
                <item android:title="item 4"
                    android:id="@+id/item4"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
                <item android:title="item 5"
                    android:id="@+id/item5"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: can you put another screen shot whatever you want

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaI I want to change color and add more padding between the items.

Comment: You can check this on GitHub... https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: For applying style you can Add some animation onClick Event LIstener ..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Step 1: Create Selector for change font color**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#bdbdbd" />
</selector>
```

**Step 2: Apply selector to navigation view by app:itemTextColor property**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/appColor"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"                               
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:itemBackground="@color/appColor"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawable_selector_drawer_item"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

Comment: Wonderful, the padding part is still there. How to change padding?

Comment: padding is defalt by android but if you want to change it than it is opposite to google material design guideLine!!

Comment: you can increase size of text but padding is right according to google material design