# How to edit menu item's style in activity_main_drawer.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, navigation-drawer, menuitem

So basically i just want to edit the style of those "menu items" which are in activity main drawer file
when i tried adding the code like `android:textColor = "@color/some"` ,it didn't worked 
My goal is to edit the style of those menu items as i don't want to keep them so boring looking 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, easiest is to use `<selector>` in styles
But since your question is very vague and non specific I have a few links for you

Check This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185891/how-to-style-menu-items-in-navigation-drawer-in-and)
and these YouTube Videos ,[This One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsOjqbpO5Js) and [This One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7338OWvpREUroid)

Sorry I can't really help you since your question doesn't supply a lot of information